# "<App> is having trouble with Google Play Services. Please try again" while usiing Google NearBy Messages API

Tags: android, kotlin, google-nearby, google-nearby-messages

While using google NearBy Messages API I am getting error " is having trouble with Google Play Services. Please try again"

Please guide me for this issue.

[image: Whnever i am publishing message. this error appears]

Below is import for Google Messaging API

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:17.0.0'
```

Here is how I am subscribing using code

```
    val options = SubscribeOptions.Builder()
        .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
        .build()
    Nearby.getMessagesClient(
        this, MessagesOptions.Builder()
            .setPermissions(NearbyPermissions.BLE)
            .build())
    Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).subscribe(getPendingIntent(), options)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it.

- Nearby suggest using activity, on activty, the function will work better (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/MessagesClient#subscribe(android.app.PendingIntent,%20com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.SubscribeOptions))

> All of the Messages APIs should be used from a foreground Activity,
> with the exception of the variants of subscribe that take a
> PendingIntent parameter. Your Activity should publish(Message) or
> subscribe(MessageListener) either in onStart() or in response to a
> user action in a visible Activity, and you should always symmetrically
> unpublish(Message) or unsubscribe(MessageListener) in onStop().

- When subcribe, if using activity, it will ask to grant permission to bluetooth, location, microphone, if using service it will not ask

**So if you use the service, you must combine using the activity.**

- When you subscribe in mainActivity, **if another activity appears on top (then MainActivty will be onStop), a notification will appear.**
  Therefore, when subcribe, you must click OK to allow the another activity to be displayed

This is sample:

MainActivity.tk

```
private val mMessageListener: MessageListener = object : MessageListener() {
        override fun onFound(message: Message) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFound message:"+ String(message.content))
        }

        override fun onLost(message: Message) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Lost sight of message: " + String(message.content))
        }
    }
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val isFirstTime = sharedPref.getBoolean("FIRST_TIME", true)
    if(isFirstTime) {
            Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).subscribe(mMessageListener).addOnCompleteListener(this, OnCompleteListener {
                requestPermissionFirstTime()
            }).addOnCanceledListener(this, OnCanceledListener {
                requestPermissionFirstTime()
            })
        } else {
            requestPermissionCapture()
            checkPermissionAccessibility()
            startService(Intent(this, NearbyMessageService::class.java))
        }

}
private fun requestPermissionFirstTime() {
        val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Utils.IAMHERE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPref.edit()
        editor.putBoolean("FIRST_TIME", false)
        editor.apply()
        Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).unsubscribe(mMessageListener)
        requestPermissionCapture()
        checkPermissionAccessibility()
    }
```

NearbyMessageService.tk

```
class NearbyMessageService: IntentService("NearbyMessageService") {
private val mMessageListener: MessageListener = object : MessageListener() {
        override fun onFound(message: Message) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFound message:"+ String(message.content))
        }

        override fun onLost(message: Message) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Lost sight of message: " + String(message.content))
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startForeground()
        Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).subscribe(mMessageListener)
    }

private fun startForeground() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channelId = "002"
            val channelName = "Nearby Service Channel"
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE)
            channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
            val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            val notification: Notification = Notification.Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .build()
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                startForeground(Utils.NOTICATION_ID_NEARBY, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION)
            } else {
                startForeground(Utils.NOTICATION_ID_NEARBY, notification)
            }
        } else {
            startForeground(Utils.NOTICATION_ID_NEARBY, Notification())
        }
    }

}
```